# Creating a 2D chart in excel with 2 Y-axes - one stacked, one non-stacked

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I'm looking to create a 2D line-chart in Excel 2007.
It will have 2 Y-axes. The X axis will be dates.
There will be 5 series.  I want 3 of the series to be stacked and use
one Y-axis, and the remaining 2 to stay unstacked and use the other Y-axis.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Get all 5 data sets onto a chart first, then there are two steps:

1. Right click on each of the ones you want on the y-axis. Select Format Data Series, and in the Series Options section change the Y axis to the secondary axis.
2. Right click on each of the ones you want to change the chart type of and select Change Series Chart Type. Then you can have a different type for each series.